# Is "black mountain" in S04E05 "Rattlestar Ricklactica" a reference to something?

Tags: reference, rick-and-morty

In *Rick and Morty* S04E05 - "*Rattlestar Ricklactica*", Rick and Morty had this conversation:

> Morty: I'm dying, Rick. [Groans] I can see the black mountain.
> Rick: People who are really dying don't keep bringing it up.
> Morty: Is that true?
> Rick: I don't know. I'm just usually around people that die faster.

I haven't heard of "black mountain" being used as an expression or idiom for dying. Is "black mountain" a reference to something?

Comment: Geographic Black Mountains that lies above Death Valley close to Funeral Moutnains in California? Sounds like a good place to die.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a reference to *[Thisby Theestoop and the Black Mountain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBShkJu15J8)*

The author, Zac Gorman, worked on the R&M comics